# Story of our Glory

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge, story, sports

### Story of X's Glory

> Let us tell you the Story of our Glory.$[\cdots (0)]$
> We started according to the new Year.
> Manual on 'How to Win'.$[\cdots (1)]$
> Everybody started exclaiming "**X**"$[\cdots (2)]$
> All began to mull over the Possibilities.$[\cdots (3)]$
> We started cruising towards our **Destination**.$[\cdots (4)]$
> We did the Maths.$[\cdots (5)]]$
> And registered a historical Win in the Semi-Final.$[\cdots (6)]$
> We had the fiercest Swans-Tiger, who was the best in Defence.$[\cdots (7)]$
> We were not going to Mess it this Time.$[\cdots (8)]$
> We knew we were surely going to Win.$[\cdots (9)]$
> We had all the Low we needed.$[\cdots (10)]$
> We came so close.$[\cdots (11)]$
> Finally, we gotz it.$[\cdots (12)]]$

---

### Question:

What does this story remind you of?
Identify **X** and the **Destination**.

---

### Note:

- Dodgy pun alert.
- Please don't edit without asking.
- Hints will be provided as and when deemed necessary.

---

### Hints:

---

> **$(1)$** Notice that the first letter of all nouns is in capital.

---

> **$(2)$** One for all and all for one.

---

> **$(3)$** Every line is valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can identify

> **X** as Germany National Football Team (**Die Mannschaft**), the **Destination** is the 2014 FIFA World Cup title.

---

### Dodgy Puns:

---

> (1) new Year = Neuer and Manual = Manuel, so Manuel Neuer.

---

> (2) exc(laim)ing = Lahm, so Phillip Lahm

---

> (3) mull over = Müller, so Thomas Müller.

---

> (4) cruising = Kroos, so Toni Kroos.

---

> (5) Maths = Mats , so Mats Hummmels.

---

> (6) Swans-Tiger = Schweinsteiger , best in = Bastian , so Bastian Schweinsteiger.

---

> (7) semi = Sami , so Sami Khedira.

---

> (8) Mess it= Mesut, so Mesut Özil.

---

> (9) surely = Schürrle, so André Schürrle.

---

> (10) Low = Löw, so Joachim Löw.

---

> (11) close = Klose, so Miroslav Klose.

---

> (12) gotz = Götze, so Mario Götze.

---

> Incidentally, my home country suffered quite a tragic loss at that semi-final :(

---

### Hints explained:

---

> (1) All of the nouns are capitalized because that happens when you write in German.

---

> (2) This hints towards unity and teamspirit, essential characteristics of a team.

---

> (3) Every line contains the name of some player disguised by a pun.

Comment: I thought Mess as Messi was a cooler solution because you don't want to mess it up :P

Comment: No idea for the semi-final line, I'll have to defer that to the experts

Comment: I decided to give you the answer for the semi-final.